# Getting non-alphanumeric characters after stripping them off

Tags: python

I am using the following regular expression to strip non-alphanumeric characters (without removing the spaces) from `string`.

```
pattern = re.compile('([^\s\w]|_)+', re.UNICODE)
```

But still, I am getting the following strings after filtering:

```
√ß
 √§√§√§  √°  √°
√†
 √•√Æ √≤√´√¢√°√§
√∂√®
√£√≥√ª√•√º√¥√ß √±√π√º
√ß √ß
√¥√π√± √∂√π√Æ √≠√Æ√™√Ø√Æ
√Æ√Ø√°√¨√µ√°√≠√∂
√π√®√µ√°√≠√∂
√≤√≠√≠√≤√™ √µ√°√≠√∂
√∏ √¢ √°√≠
√•√Æ√¶√≠√Æ
√≠√≠√∂ √π√Æ√≤√µ√†√§
√§
 √®√®√± √±√π√º
√®√®√± √±√π√º
√§√≥√≤√•√¥ √™√£
√Ø√π√π√Ø√§√≥ √±√π√º
√º√≠√ª√ß√¥√±√≥ √±√π√º
```

How can I deal with them using regular expression? I want the above string to become an empty string after removing non-alphanumeric chars.

I have a list of user queries which I am trying to pre-process. I am providing the concerned code snippet as follows.

```
query_text = ' '.join([pattern.sub(' ', word) for word in tokens[1].lower().split()])
query_text = query_text.strip()
```

Please note:

- The problem I am dealing with is removing any non-alphanumeric character except space given a String.
- Remove non-alphanumeric characters based on English language.

Comment: You just show the code where you compile the expression.  Where is the code where you actually *use* it?

Comment: @BrenBarn added.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. What's the filtering here? The `pattern.sub`?

Comment: Non-alphanumeric characters based on which language? English / Latin?

Comment: I am trying to remove non-alphanumeric characters based on English. Yes, the `pattern.sub` is the filtering process here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `re.UNICODE` flag (and, at least in my version of Python, also without it), the class `\w` includes many "non-English" alphanumeric characters, such as Greek letters, umlauts, ligatures, and others. If you want to remove those, too, you should not use `\w` but a more "explicit" character class such as `a-zA-Z0-9`.

```
>>> pattern = re.compile('([^\s\w]|_)+', re.UNICODE)
>>> pattern.sub("", text)
'ß\n     \n\n Æ \n\nªºß πº\nß ß\nπ πÆ ÆØÆ\nÆØµ\nπµ\n µ\n  \nÆÆ\n πÆµ\n\n  πº\n πº\n \nØππØ πº\nºªß πº'
>>> pattern = re.compile('[^\sa-zA-Z0-9]+', re.UNICODE)
>>> pattern.sub("", text)
'\n     \n\n  \n\n \n \n  \n\n\n \n  \n\n \n\n  \n \n \n \n '
```

Or you could explicitly set the `re.ASCII` flag so that `\w` is actually equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

```
>>> re.sub("[^\s\w]", "", text, flags=re.UNICODE)
'ß\n     \n\n Æ \n\nªºß πº\nß ß\nπ πÆ ÆØÆ\nÆØµ\nπµ\n µ\n  \nÆÆ\n πÆµ\n\n  πº\n πº\n \nØππØ πº\nºªß πº'
>>> re.sub("[^\s\w]", "", text, flags=re.ASCII)
'\n     \n\n  \n\n \n \n  \n\n\n \n  \n\n \n\n  \n \n \n \n '
```